# MATLAB: Undefined function 'string' for input arguments of type 'char'?

Tags: matlab

```
A = 'Four score and seven years ago';
str = string(A);
```

With version R2016a I get error:

```
Undefined function 'string' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

How can I have two strings array without using 'string':

```
str(1) = 'foo';
str(2) = 'bar';
```

?

I need to reference the two in `file_id = fopen(str(i), 'wb');`

Comment: Probably because you are using a Matlab version that is not recent enough to have `string`

Comment: [`string`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) was introduced in 2016b version. What MATLAB version do you have?

Comment: 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a) :-(

Comment: Use a cell array instead `str = strsplit('foo bar')` is the same as `str = {'foo', 'bar'};` which gives `str{1} = 'foo'`

Comment: Thanks Wolfie. Please add this as answer.

Comment: check with `which` function for knowing that your version has this function or not  `>>which string`     my test->`>> which string
string is a built-in method  % string constructor`

Answer (score 1):

You can define your strings into a cell array and access them in loop.

```
str = {'foo' 'bar'} ;
str{1}
str{2}
```